# Efficiently ordering locations by their geographical distance from a query point

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, location, distance

I'm trying to find a method that efficiently, possibly O(log(n)), finds a given number of closest locations to a query location given their geographical coordinates (lat, lon).

The query point is not known in advance, but I can organize the other locations in advance in order to optimize the query.

Is there such a method or do I have to order and crop a list of all peers?

Answer (score 0):

If your surface satisfy the triangle inequality, i.e. is an euklidian space the best algorithm to reorder a spatial index is a space filling curve or a monster curve. It reduces the 2d problem to a 1d problem and discretize and solve the adressing of the space. The lookup up for similar locations is something like O(log(n)). You can find a good article at nick spatial index hilbert curve quadtree blog. I suggest to look at n-ary monotonic gray codes, too. I wrote myself a php implementation including hilbert curve in 4 directions and the moore curve.